# Creating DOM elements with different text

Tags: javascript, html

I’m trying to dynamically create DOM elements that display each object value for all objects in the array.

I used a for loop to create the elements and tried matching content iterations to the array iterations, but it doesn’t work. Below is my code (this is a simplified version to get the code working).

```
let divTwo = document.querySelector('.div-two');
let bigArray = [{
    first: 'Joe',
    location: 'Washington'
  },
  {
    first: 'Jon',
    location: 'Boston'
  },
  {
    first: 'Brian',
    location: 'New York'
  },
];
let smallArray = ['first', 'location'];

function addNames() {
  for (let i = 0; i < bigArray.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < smallArray.length; j++) {
      let newSpan = document.createElement('span');

      newSpan.id = 'spanny' + (j + 1);
      divTwo.appendChild(newSpan);
      document.getElementById('spanny1').textContent = bigArray[j].first;
      document.getElementById('spanny2').textContent = bigArray[j].location;

      // newSpan[0].textContent = bigArray[0].first;     *also doesn’t work*
      // newSpan[1].textContent = bigArray[0].location;  *also doesn’t work*
    }
  }
}

addNames();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t really want to add these IDs to the `<span>`s, since they will appear three times each on your page, which is invalid.

You’re probably looking for something like this. You want to get the `i`-th element of `bigArray`, then get the value associated with the key given by the `j`-th element in `smallArray`. So use `bigArray[i][smallArray[j]]`.

```
function addNames() {
  for (let i = 0; i < bigArray.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < smallArray.length; j++) {
      let newSpan = document.createElement("span");

      divTwo.appendChild(newSpan);
      newSpan.textContent = bigArray[i][smallArray[j]];
    }
  }
}
```

It’s cleaner using ECMAScript 6+:

```
function addNames() {
  bigArray.forEach((data) => divTwo.append(...smallArray.map((key) => Object.assign(document.createElement("span"), {
    textContent: data[key]
  }))));
}
```